# Blackberry Webworks application not loading remote page on simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

My Blackberry Webworks application is having problem opening a remote page when testing it in a Blackberry simulator (Tried 9630-Verizon, 9700-ATT, 9860-Asia). Each time I try to open a remote page in my webworks application, the application will freeze and after a while i get a white screen with the error `App Error 104 Uncaught: InterruptedIOException` and when I click continue a message dialog comes up with the message `Local Connection timed out after ~ 120000`. If i open that same URL in the simulator's browser, it opens straight away. What I don't know is why it's not opening in the webworks application.

Now, the funniest part is, if I load the same webworks application into my blackberry device, it works perfectly. It opens the remote page straight away. I don't know why its not working in a simulator.

I have the `config.xml` file configured properly with the remote url set in the access element `<access uri="http://sample-remote-server.com/" subdomains="true" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to fix the problem. For future reference, the problem was, I wasn't running MDS so the Blackberry simulator couldn't simulate data service.

To fix the problem, I just navigated to the **mds folder** in my Blackberry Webworks path usually at `\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Webworks SDK\mds` and clicked on `run.bat` and MDS Server will be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

i am currently using Ripple 0.9.0.16 beta with the 4.0.0.127 simulator, and they're both a little buggy.

when you first launch your widget the emulator loads properly and the mds is started. however, upon closing the emulator (resetting crashes it) and re-opening, which must be done manually because ripple doesn't if you choose "Package & Launch", the mds was not restarted and my requests were never answered.

this caused a lot of frustration until i saw your post and executed run.bat, which allowed the service to respond to my request.

thanks user431949